# VueJS slot in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a grid component which accepts as slot additional column cell.

```
<grid>
  <td slot="additional-column">...</td>
</grid>
```

In the actual component:

```
<template>
   <table>
     <div v-for="item in items">
       ...
       <slot name="additional-column"></slot>
     </div>
   </table>
</template>
```

Unfortunately the slot starts repeating itself and this is something vuejs doesn't like.

> Duplicate presence of slot "additional-column" found in the same render tree - this will likely cause render errors.

Does anybody know how can I deal with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Duplicate-Slots-removed) definitely seems to be your issue. You could do it this way too (as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots)). See last paragraph before the subheading `Destructuring`.

Parent:

```
<grid>
  <td :slot="['additional-column', item].join('-')" v-for="item in items">
  ...
  </td>
</grid>
```

Child:

```
<table>
    <div v-for="item in items">
        ...
        <slot :name="['additional-column', item].join('-')"></slot>
    </div>
</table>
```

PS: I have NOT tried this out. If you have difficulties I could create a fiddle and share.

Comment: and for those seeking to insert arbitrary number of columns and getting `'<template>' cannot be keyed` error: when inserting a `<template>` into an iterated slot, you can put the `:key` bit into each `<td>` inside the `<template>` instead which will fix the issue

Comment: Why use an array with a join when JS String Interpolation would do the same thing?
:slot="additional-column-${item}"? (Have to wrap the string content with back-ticks, which I can't do in this comment because SO keeps vanishing them into code -_-;)

Comment: Please pay attention that [dynamic slot names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names) work since the 2.6.0 version

Answer (score 6):

Make the item a nested component (which you'll be repeating using `v-for`) and render the `additional-column` slot in that particular component.

That's the proper way to overcome this issue. The idea is that you need to have one single slot with a particular name per component.

That is, you could do it that way, which is a very rough version of it but nicely outlines the idea:

```
<!-- Grid Template -->
<template>
  <table>
    <GridItem :item="item" v-for="item in items">
      <!-- Maybe even pass that column conditionally, based on the item data -->
      <div slot="additional-column">
        Content of column
      </div>
    </GridItem>
  </table>
</template>


<!-- GridItem Template -->
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <slot name="additional-column" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you elaborate on that? Perhaps an example code?

Comment: I've added a small snippet of code where I allow someone to pass an `additional-column` into the `GridItem` component. You can even pass that `additional-column` conditionally, with a `v-if`.

Comment: OK, but in my case the passing of slot\html comes from a component which is using the grid component. My understanding is that what you propose is something like double slotting. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking. Users of your `Grid` component should not be aware about this double slotting. It just happened that you implemented it that way.